How to approximate a Fx swap PnL by implied rates and dv01
I just joined the trading floor and have a blunt question about fx swap. Say I long (s/b) 1y USDJPY fx swap with a positive dv01 of 1000usd. Instead of using notional values and swap points to calculate PnL, could I use 1y sofr rate, 1y JPY implied rate and dv01 to do the same thing? code
Say s/b 1y USDJPY with 1000dv. 1y JPY implied rate decreases 3bp while 1y SOFR rate also decreases 1bp code
My guess is PnL should be close to 1000*(-3-(-1))=-2000 code
Please correct me if I misunderstand anything. Thanks for any insight shared in advance!

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2011809
